# /dev/null-like automatic trash directory for file moves?

Tags: shell-script, files, trash

I can (redirect) textual output to `/dev/null` in order to get rid of it. This is quite handy because this way I can easily enable/disable it in my bash code.

Now I have a script that processes files, and after it is done with them, moves them to another destination. An simple example would look like this:

```
source_dir=some/source/path
target_dir=some/target/path
for f in `ls $source_dir`; do echo $f; mv $f $target_dir; done
```

Now when I decide that I'm no longer interested in moving the files to the target dir, but to delete the files directement, what is the most efficient way to achieve this (in terms of lines of code to edit)?

I can think of putting the `mv` command into a variable as well:

```
process_cmd=echo
finnish_cmd=mv
source_dir=some/source/path
target_dir=some/target/path
for f in `ls $source_dir`; do $process_cmd $f; $finnish_cmd $f $target_dir; done
```

Then I could later change to something like:

```
process_cmd=echo
finnish_cmd=rm
source_dir=some/source/path
target_dir=
for f in `ls $source_dir`; do $process_cmd $f; $finnish_cmd $f $target_dir; done
```

But I thought it would be even simpler, if it was possible to specify a `/dev/null`-like trash target directory that is automatically cleaned up eventually (that is sort of `rm` semantics with the `mv` command):

```
process_cmd=echo
finnish_cmd=mv
source_dir=some/source/path
target_dir=/dev/null # <--- is there some sort of trash folder for such tasks?
for f in `ls $source_dir`; do $process_cmd $f; $finnish_cmd $f $target_dir; done
```

Is there a definitive way to go / a general best practice for a case like this?

Comment: I genuinely don't understand why you are making things so complicated. Use `rm`. Directly.

Comment: And don't ever [parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) with anything but your eyes.

Comment: Move it to ramfs drive, it will disappear or reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such place for a fairly straightforward reason: there isn't any use for one.  There is no situation I can think of where you can use `mv` globally but not `rm`.  So while `/dev/null` exists because it meets a need, `/dir/garbage` does not because it would not.

Of course, you could say there is a need in this situation, to do with the issue: "what is the most efficient way to achieve this (in terms of lines of code to edit)?"  Presuming the mechanism determining which files should be moved vs. deleted is whether `target_dir` is defined or not:

```
if [ -n "$target_dir" ]; then
    # move file
else
    # delete file
fi
```

Pretty simple, and you don't have to re-edit anything (I presume by "edit" you didn't mean something about *maintenance* or reducing the number of lines, because doing something in a an awkward, hack, or incorrect manner in the name of "simpler maintenance" -- or worse yet, pseudo-cleverness -- is oxymoronic).

That said, you could fairly easily implement your own garbage directory by running a cron job like this once an hour:

```
garbage_dir=/usr/local/garbage
for file in $garbage_dir/*; do
    rm -f -R $file;
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are simply looking for the `/tmp` directory. In most cases, anything you place there will be removed next time you reboot. The details depend on your specific OS and are governed by the value of the `$TMPTIME` variable. For many distributions, the default is clearing `/tmp` every boot because `$TMPTIME` is set to 0. In most (if not all) distributions, this is set in the file `/etc/default/rcS`.

So, just do something like this (note that I am using shell globbing and *not* parsing `ls`):

```
process_cmd=echo
finish_cmd=mv
source_dir=some/source/path
target_dir=/tmp
for f in $source_dir/*; do $process_cmd "$f"; $finish_cmd "$f" $target_dir; done
```

Comment: +1 for the globbing/quoting. But not every system deletes `/tmp` on reboot, or reboots at all for that matter. If you want something to be deleted *directement* (as the question states), `rm` it will have to be.

Comment: @frostschutz I added some more details on how/when the `/tmp` is cleared, but the OP wanted to "specify a /dev/null-like trash target directory that is automatically cleaned up eventually". That is exactly what `/tmp` is for.

Comment: Using `/tmp` as a dustbin sounds like a completely HORRENDOUS idea to me.  It obviously is *not intended* for this purpose and you are putting a gun to your foot using it for such.

Comment: @goldilocks what do you mean?`/tmp` is designed for placing things you don't care about that will be deleted without warning. That seems to be exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: *That is not at all what it is for*.  It is for storage of temporary files; tmp files are essentially a programming related conceit and they *do* have a purpose. They are not "things you don't care about that can be deleted without warning"; they are things whose use value will not continue beyond the runtime of the process which created them (hence, temporary), and they certainly  should never ever be deleted "without warning".

Comment: @goldilocks temporary files are temporary files, whether they were created manually or not makes no difference, the point is that they are _temporary_. I don't see what the problem is, the `/tmp` directory is there [specifically](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES) for storing files whose fate you don't care about and are deleted without warning: "Although data stored in /tmp may be deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that files and directories located in /tmp be deleted whenever the system is booted."

Comment: The point is, it is not for garbage (none of the files you'll find there normally are garbage), and while this may work for some people in some situations, it is not a good solution: it's prone to overfilling `/tmp` (which may be a separate, smaller partition, or even in memory on some systems) and rendering it useless for its real purpose, and it is also a security concern (consider: "I'm done with these bank statements, I will just leave them on a park bench, because someone will clean them up eventually").

Comment: `mv` will happily overwrite any files existing in `/tmp` (unless your `mv` is an alias to `mv -i`), probably still needed by other processes. It's a very bad idea to (over)write random files in `/tmp` and not ensure unique filenames. And @goldilocks is right with overfilling `/tmp`. The `/tmp` on my desktop is on a ramdisk, for example.